# Query if Hide Selected is enabled via Python

Tags: python, 3d-view

Is there a way to query if the Hide Selected is currently enabled on the model?

I would like to query that with a Python script.

Select a face of a mesh and press H. I want to know if I am in that mode.

Comment: Hello, just to be clear You'd like to know if at least one face is hidden in edit mode ?

Comment: basically yes, that is what I need